# Why can I bind either String or LiveData<string> varaiable to android:text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm learning data binding, the following code is from the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-databinding).

The `android:text` in *plain_activity_solution_3.xml* bind to `SimpleViewModel` with `name` which is `String.`

The `android:text` in *solution.xml* bind to `SimpleViewModelSolution` with `name` which is `LiveData<String>`.

Why can either `String` or `LiveData<string>` be bind to `android:text`? In my mind , only one is allowed to be bind to  `android:text`.

**SimpleViewModel.kt**

```
class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val name = "Grace"
    val lastName = "Hopper"
    var likes = 0
        private set // This is to prevent external modification of the variable.
    ...
}
```

**plain_activity_solution_3.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.android.databinding.basicsample.data.SimpleViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plain_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"
    ...
}
```

**SimpleViewModelSolution.kt**

```
class SimpleViewModelSolution : ViewModel() {
    private val _name = MutableLiveData("Ada")
    private val _lastName = MutableLiveData("Lovelace")
    private val _likes =  MutableLiveData(0)

    val name: LiveData<String> = _name
    val lastName: LiveData<String> = _lastName
    val likes: LiveData<Int> = _likes
    ...
}
```

**solution.xml**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.android.databinding.basicsample.data.SimpleViewModelSolution"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- A simple binding between a TextView and a string observable in the ViewModel -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, and discussed in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture).  The binder will accept either the native data type, or something that's "Observable", like LiveData.  If an observable object is provided, the binder will subscribe to the object's changes and bind those to the view, saving you lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

As the [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability) says:

> Any plain-old object can be used for data binding, but modifying the object doesn't automatically cause the UI to update. Data binding can be used to give your data objects the ability to notify other objects, known as listeners, when its data changes.

`LiveData<string>` is observable, too.